# How to upload images to a database with other details using postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman

I want to upload a image with other details like employee id, employee name etc using spring boot and spring data jpa, trying to send request using postman.I have searched a lot but I cannot find any examples sending both image and other details in one method, as I am a fresher unable to find exact solution and also I don't want to use ObjectMapper to read values.Can some one help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: **"I have searched a lot"** - I really think you have not searched a lot. Search for "how to create a REST API with spring boot". Then search "for spring data JPA with spring boot". Then Search for "how to upload an image with spring boot". These search queries gave me more than enough results to start with. If you have any doubts while following these, please feel free to ask. Your question is too broad and lacks effort.

Comment: @k9yosh thank you and yes for sure I'll let you know if I have any concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Example:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public Object getConsumedUser(
        @Valid User user,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    return file;
}

-----------

class User {
 private String name;
 private String username;

 //Getter and Setter
 ...

}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer but @RequestParam("title") String title works only for one field but I want to send more than one field may be like a whole entity class,which doesn't seems so good if I write so many @RequestParam's, right?

Comment: @Akki !! check again my post i edited it , may help you this time ^^

Comment: yes I'll check it out but why @Valid?

Comment: In order to validate the User object or else it will throw an exception !!

Comment: May I know which exception is thrown?

Comment: take a look : [MethodArgumentNotValidException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html) 
 ( don'f forget to check my post as the anwser if it give you the solution )

Comment: how to send List<User> data as form-data in postman

Comment: @Alekya i think your can't pass list of users at same times at this position or else you can do it by sending the list of users which is parsed to a string, then you will use jackson to parse it again to a java object